# PHP/MYSQL UPDATE not writing to the database

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update a database with a constant, Guest. I have an array containing dates, and have set a `for` loop to cycle through them, the query should amend one row whos date matches the array key `AND` the `starttime` of 19:00:00. However it is not amending the database. Where am i going wrong?

```
$size1 = sizeof($dayOfTheWeek) - 1;


for ($count = 0; $count <= $size1; $count++) {


$query = "UPDATE rota SET title=Guest WHERE date = '$dateMonthYearArr[$count]' AND starttime = '19:00:00'" or die;               
$dayresult = mysql_query($query); 

echo "".$dateMonthYearArr[$count]."</br>";
}

echo "Complete";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "UPDATE rota SET title='Guest' WHERE date = '" . $dateMonthYearArr[$count] . "' AND starttime = '19:00:00'";
```

You should also make sure $dateMonthYearArr[$count] is SQL safe =).

Answer (score 1):

Fix query:

```
$query = "UPDATE rota SET title='Guest' 
          WHERE date = '" . $dateMonthYearArr[$count] . "' AND starttime = '19:00:00'";               
$dayresult = mysql_query($query);
```

`$dateMonthYearArr` is a php array so you should concatenate it to your string in a proper way.

Comment: Good catch.  Didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

This actually

```
$query = "UPDATE rota SET title=Guest WHERE date = '$dateMonthYearArr[$count]' AND starttime = '19:00:00'" or die;
```

is a comparison because 'or' is an operator and it behaves like an IF-statement. So your are not setting the string properly.

Try it with:

```
$query = "UPDATE rota SET title = 'Guest' WHERE date = '" . $dateMonthYearArr[$count] . "' AND starttime = '19:00:00'";
mysql_query($query) or die('Cannot update title');
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my other answer and combined the points of the other two posters.  Please do not award me points for this.  I just combined their [better] answers.

```
<?php

$query = "UPDATE rota SET title = 'Guest' WHERE date = '".$dateMonthYearArr[$count]."' AND starttime = '19:00:00'";
mysql_query($query) or die('Cannot update title');
```